# Removing last char from textfield without destroying textformat

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3

i have a problem where i want to remove the last character from a textfield (including linebreaks) that has multiple textformats without removing the formats.

so far i have:

```
textfield.replaceText(textField.length-1,textField.length-1,'');
```

i guess this doesn't remove linebreaks, and is very slow, seems to destroy my textformats.

or:

```
textfield.text = textfield.text.slice(0,-1);
```

this is faster but removes all textformats as well.

Comment: Woa, being downvoted two years later... What gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bit tedious, but you can use the `htmlText`-property of TextField, even though you are not formatting your text with StyleSheets: Flash will transform all your formatting information into HTML text internally, so even though you set `textField.text`, you can still get xml formatted text to work with:

```
textField.text = "A test.";
trace (textField.htmlText);
```

will actually return:

```
<P ALIGN="LEFT"><FONT FACE="Times Roman" SIZE="12" COLOR="#000000" LETTERSPACING="0" KERNING="0">A test.</FONT></P>
```

Text will always appear within `<FONT>` tags reflecting the changes you made using `setTextFormat()`.  You can, therefore, iterate over the XML contained in this line, and remove only the last character in the last TextNode:

```
private function removeLastCharacter (textField:TextField) : void {
    var xml:XML = new XML (textField.htmlText);
    for ( var i : int = xml.children().length()-1; i >= 0; i-- ){
        var node:XML = xml.children()[i];
        if ( node.name() == "FONT") {
            var tx:String = node.text()[0].toString();
            node.setChildren (tx.substr (0, tx.length-1));
            break;
        }
    }
    textField.htmlText = xml; 
    trace (textField.text); // In the above example, output will be: "A test";
}
```

Comment: This could really work, i suspect it would be really slow for my problem tho. i need to contain the text inside a textfield so that it don't overflow. The current solution being that i remove last character while textfield is larger than its container. Maby i can get around this in some other way. Now im facing a new problem with font-size limit of 127 for the textfield class and might have to switch to TLF. This is turning out to be a real nightmare...

Comment: It's not going to be very slow.  The XML conversion is done by Flash, anyway.  You can get around the size limit by scaling the TextField: A font size of 128, for example, would be font size:64 at scale 2.  You can use the same parsing mechanism to multiply all font sizes by a scale factor, so everything smaller than 127 will also still look the same.

Comment: Sorry, I just re-read your comment... Why don't you use getCharIndexAtPoint?

Comment: by scaling you mean to scale the whole textfield? don't know if this will work because i need to be able to have multiple font-sizes in the same textfield. for example i can have a row with font size of 124 and another with the font size of 300. scaling the whole textfield will mean i have to recalculate the lower font to a smaller size and scale up so that the larger is correct?

Comment: how would getCharIndexAtPoint solve the problem with loosing of textformat?

Comment: Yes, I meant scaling the whole TextField.  You need to find out the largest font size you want to display, scale the field to the next highest multiple of 127 ( for example, if your font size is 300, scale to 3 ), and divide all font sizes by that same factor.

Comment: getCharIndexAtPoint(bottomright.x, bottomright.y) will help you find the index of the last character you want to display.  Then, instead of eating away letter by letter from the end of the text, just count the characters inside your `<FONT>` tags until you've reached the character index. You can then clear all text after that by simply setting the text inside all `<FONT>` tags to `""`. If that is even necessary - you could also set maxChars.

Comment: I'll see if i can make that work for the fontsize. For getCharIndexAtPoint im not sure it will work but i'll try that aswell, sounds like a really smart solution. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understand your problem correctly. If you keep your formatting in htmlText, I have one possible solution:

The idea is to keep the formatted text in an XML format, and modify the XML. XML will keep your formatting intact, you don't have to do string aerobatics to maintain them. The downsides are of course having to keep the formatting XML valid, and the extra variable.

Here's an example:

```
var tf:TextField = new TextField();
var t:XML = new XML("<html><p>lalala</p><font color='#ff0000'> lol</font></html>"); 
tf.htmlText = t.toXMLString();
t.font[0] = t.font[0].text().slice(0, -1);
tf.htmlText = t.toXMLString();
addChild(tf);
```

Comment: Thanks for this but i am not using htmlText for this project, and i guess this would mean a major rewrite to my rather huge project. I am just looking for a simpler solution so that i can remove the character (or linebreak) at the end of the text string without totaly removing all textformats within the textfield.

Comment: is it possible to see some more code snippets, to see how you set up the multiple text formats?

Comment: well, it's a bit complicated to post here, but it involves an XML a handle class for paragraphs, a extended textfield class and a bunch code. basically i get my formats for the textfield (created dynamically) from xml, i have a bunch of controlls for changing font, size, leading, color (with support for multiple colors: cmyk, rgb, pms etc). i translate a textformat class to xml to store my settings. I use the same method to save "paragraph styles" wich is further dynamic in it self. To make this short im making a word-like application dedicated for print.

Comment: Basicly i set my textformat by calling a bunch of textfield.setTextFormat(theTextFormat,startindex,endindex); This project is quite complicated as is and i would really like to avoid having to use htmlText because i think that would only further complicated my project with very small benefits.

Comment: If I can't reproduce a similar scenario locally, I can't brainstorm over it to help you find a solution, sorry :( I hope someone else ran into something similar and would share the experience.